# IOS : 3rd party dynamic framework inside a static library

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

Is it possible to embed a dynamic framework inside a static library in such way that when using the .a lib in other projects, there is no need to use link framework/embed binaires.

So using the framework inside the static library just by using the header name.

If so, how is it done?

THANKS.

Comment: I am also looking for same solution. Did you find it ?

Comment: Got any solution? @technerd

Comment: @IBomnes any solution?